# Window 7 is Not Using the Recycle Bin for Disks Mounted Using a Junction

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I have a data volume which is mounted into C:\Data using a junction, and the drive has no letter mapping. When I delete a file from this drive, it gives me the delete permanently confirmation and does not use the recycle bin.  This happens for all files, even those near the root with short filenames.

When I delete a file from the C: drive it does use the recycle bin.

I have checked the registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IDE
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msahci\Controller0
```

and the only drive flagged as removable is my eSATA external drive.  In addition there is a TreatAsInternalPort for each of the internal drives (my data volume is actually a RAID mirror).

When I check the recycler settings, it *does* have a size for both `Data` and `System`, which are the names of my drives as configured in Computer Management and the size is set for 20 GiB each.

When I check the hidden files/folders there *is* a $RECYCLE.BIN folder on the data drive.

So, how can I make Windows 7 use the recycle bin for my data?  And specifically the recycle bin on that drive?